# Check for an element until found and click on the element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Hi i need to check for an element using python Selenium. If the element is found then i in need to click on it or else click on the next page and search the element again.This continues until the element is found.

The code i have used is :

```
 1. element_path="//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]" 
 2. while True: 
 3.  if(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath)): 
          driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_xpath).click() 
 4.  else: driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to goto next page").click()
```

But this code doesn't work as I'm getting an error:
**no such element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"}**

Can this looping be done in any other method?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: This can work, but you need to wait for element to be rendered on the front end. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable for more info.

Comment: what's site address? stale element reference error, no such element error is dynamic problem

Comment: @MateMrše i have added a **driver.implicitely_wait(1).**

Comment: @Dreamcatcher_AR 1 second might not be enough in all cases. Explicit waits are generally speaking a better solution. But if you choose to use implicit waits, try with 5 seconds just to be safe the button has time to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need to refresh the page also, but I think you should check for `len()` function that will have `find_elements` with the **xpath** you have mentioned.

try this instead  :

```
while True:
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]")) > 0:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]").click()
            break
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath to goto next page").click()
            break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you for the Reply.
This doesnt work. im getting : **Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1072 Getting Default Adaptor failed.**

Comment: and if i remove the try and except im getting **no such element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"}**

Comment: When you print `len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"))` this what is the value ?

Comment: i changed the code a bit:
``element_path="//span[contains(text(),'ABC Company')]"``
``print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath)))``
```
and im not getting anythin in the output as length
and in the above format if i do im getting the same error

Comment: and when i tried with ``element_path="//span[contains(text(),'123')]" `` ``print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(element_xpath)))``
where **123** is an element in the 1st page:
im getting **TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()**